# Identity - Password hasher dosen't generate the same hashes

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, identity

I'm trying to compare two hashes generated by PasswordHasher func, I don't know why if password and confirmPassword have the same string, "if" return false.

```
string passwordHash = UserManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(password);
string confirmPasswordHash = UserManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(confirmPassword);
  if (passwordHash != confirmPasswordHash)
  {
     ModelState.AddModelError("", "Not the same");
     return View(user);
  }

private AppUserManager UserManager
{
  get { return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<AppUserManager>(); }
}
```

So how to properly comparing hashes?

Comment: Use String.Equals? Maybe it's saying that they do not share the same memory address

Comment: Why do you need to compare the hashed versions? Why not compare `password` directly to `confirmPassword`?

Comment: Maybe the real question is why are you not hashing the password on the client machine and then sending back to your server?

Comment: Anthony: But can I do it with Identity?
mason: I could, but I wanted to check something, and I don't know why PasswordHasher generate diffrent hash for the same string?

Comment: it's explained very clearly in the duplicate post how the Hasher uses a Key Derivation Function which includes a random salt in it's output.  To verify the hash, the output is split back apart again to retrieve the salt.

Comment: It;s not the same question, it's more specific and concise.